# Get address from geocoder like autocomplete google maps

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, autocomplete, angular-cli

I use `AutoComplete` of google maps.

When I choose location from the list I get the place from `autoComplete.getPlace()` function, and there is a variable called `adr_address` and it's value look like this:

```
"<span class="street-address">xxx</span>, <span class="locality">xxx</span>, <span class="country-name">xxx</span>"
```

My problem is when I write the address by myself and not select from the list, then I dont have `adr_address` variable in `getPlace` function and I check the address with `Geocoder` if the status OK I want to get same result like I have in `adr_address`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get adr_address from Geocoder by place_id and PlacesService.

```
new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({"address":text }, function(results, status){
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
                            service.getDetails({
                                placeId: results[0].place_id
                            }, function(place, status) {
                                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                                    doSomething(place.adr_address);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            //geocode fail
                        }
                    });
```